# Как воспользоваться коллекцией в WHERE клаузе с условием IN?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Возможно ли сделать что-то вроде следующего?

```
create or replace TYPE "TypeKeys" IS TABLE OF INTEGER;
/
Declare
    Keys TypeKeys;
    personT PERSON%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    Keys := TypeKeys();
    Keys.EXTEND(2);
    Keys(1) := 14;
    Keys(2) := 21;

    SELECT * INTO personT FROM PERSON WHERE ID IN (Keys);
END;
/
```

Нужно найти записи по нескольким ID, которые содержатся в коллекции.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [It's possible to use a collection in WHERE clausule and condition IN?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65602953) от участника [@Isaac Perez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10598984/isaac-perez)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/65602953

Answer (score 3):

Следует проверять условие вхождения в коллекцию - [MEMBER Condition](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Multiset-Conditions.html#GUID-228D6708-37E1-4C54-8715-7EC2CF5B5998).

Или классически, получить лист значений в подзапросе с [Table Collection Expression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6).

Оба варианта в воспроизводимом примере:

```
create table person (id, name) as
    select  1, 'xxx' from dual union all 
    select 14, 'aaa' from dual union all 
    select 21, 'bbb' from dual
/
create or replace type typeKeys is table of integer
/
declare
    keys typeKeys := typeKeys (14, 21);
    type personT is table of person%rowtype;
    pers personT;
begin
    select * bulk collect into pers 
    from person 
    where id member of Keys
    union all 
    select * 
    from person 
    where id in (select column_value from table (Keys));
    for i in 1..pers.count loop 
        dbms_output.put_line ('row='||pers(i).id||' '||pers(i).name); 
    end loop;    
end;
/

row=14 aaa  
row=21 bbb  
row=14 aaa  
row=21 bbb
```